# Rendering nested array object values into JSX element

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, methods, jsx

I have a nested array of objects that looks something like this:

```
[
  {
    _Category: "Animals",
    _Child: {
       _Obj: [{_Title: "Monkey", _Link: "www.monkeys.com"}], [{_Title: "Monkey", _Link: "www.monkeys.com"}], etc
    }
  },
  {
    _Category: "Fruit",
    _Child: {
       _Obj: [{_Title: "Apple", _Link: "www.apples.com"}], [{_Title: "Pineapple", _Link: "www.pineapples.com"}], etc
    }
  }
]
```

I'm trying to append the `_Title` and `_Link` of each group into a JSX element. I've been able to render the `_Categories` without a problem, but the nested values are giving me a hard time.

When I go to the Elements in DevTools, I can *see* that there are 11 different groups for each item---which is how many array of objects there are under that particular category---but the `_Titles` and `_Links` are empty.

In the code below, I mapped through the `_Category` data and displayed the Categories that way. Do I have to do something similar for the `_Child` object---another map, maybe, or something else?

---

**Code:**

```
Element = ({ cats }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            {cats
                .filter((cat) => cat._Root === "Quick Links")
                .map((cat) => (
                    
                 <>
                  <div className={"colFor-" + cat._Category}>
                    <h5>{cat._Category}</h5>

                    {cat._Child._Obj.map((item) => (
                        <>
                            <a href={item._Link}>
                                <p>{item._Title}</p>
                            </a>
                            <br />
                        </>
                    ))}
                        
                   </div>
                  </>
                ))
            }
            
        </div>
    )
  }
```

Here's what `cats` looks like:

[image]

---

**Update:** As @Dominik pointed out, the way my obj was set up was incorrect so I changed it.

Comment: Did you mean `_Obj` inside `_Child` to be an array maybe? Your JSON is not valid the way you added it.

Comment: @Dominik you're right, it was meant to be an array. When I go to the Elements in DevTools, I can now see that there are 11 different groups for each item---which is how many arrays of objects there are under that particular category---but the `_Titles` and `_Links` divs are empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your sample data, cat._Child._Obj is an array and each item in it is also an array, so I think you need to flat you array first then use the map function.

```js
const myarr = [[{_Title: "Monkey1", _Link: "www.monkeys1.com"}], [{_Title: "Monkey2", _Link: "www.monkeys1.com"}]];
const myarrFlat = myarr.flat();
myarrFlat.map(cat => console.log(cat._Title, cat._Link));
```

Comment: Hey @Eric, I flattened the array and did a bit of tinkering, and I was able to get the data to display. I ran `flat()` after `_Child` and then returned the elements---it's worth noting that I adjusted how my `_Child` obj was created and cut out the middle man. In other words, I no longer had to do `cat._Child._Obj`...etc.

`{cat._Child.flat().map((item) => { return ( <a key={item._ID} ...`